# OpenVPN Client Separate Outgoing and Incoming?

Tags: networking, server, openvpn

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server. I am using this server for a couple of services that I want to access internally and externally. I have setup port forwarding (forwarding different external ports to different internal ports) on my router and everything is OK, as I can access my server on the desired ports.

My design problem happens when I use OpenVPN client on my server.  I want the server to use OpenVPN for outgoing traffic, but I want the incoming traffic to use my WAN (ISP). So I have currently configured OpenVPN, and that seems to be working for all outgoing traffic from what I can see. However, the incoming traffic seems to be affected in some way, as I can no longer connect to my server externally on the ISP External IP, as I once did.  As soon as I stop the OpenVPN client service, my access is then restored.

I see the tun0 was created when OpenVPN client starts up with a 172 address and I have a enp0s31f6 NIC with my LAN IP.

I have also disabled the UFW for testing purposes.

Not sure if this information helps at all, but when I enable OpenVPN, I am connected to the network internally and I try to use the external WAN ISP IP on the desired ports, I can gain access to the server fine. But if that same setup is in place and I am now external, the connection is no longer there. Hope that makes sense.

Any suggestions would be great, because I am a little stuck. I don't know if it is routing or a client configuration change etc responsible for this.  I feel it is routing.....

Even if someone has a decent guide i can follow to allow this i can start again

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! I am not really sure about your setup from your question, please [edit] it to explain. Is your Ubuntu Server is running OpenVPN _Client_? Don’t the native and OpenVPN IP addresses interfere?

Comment: I think I need to use VPN Split Tunnel, going to see if i can implement it and report back